# Error 0xc00000e9 when trying to install Win8.1 from CD on a new SSD device

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, windows-installation, windows-error-reporting

I've just connected my new old SSD drive into my main computer. I have Win7 already installed on the old HDD and I want to install a new one (Win8.1) on the SSD. When I try booting from the CD drive, I get that error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ZyGP93u.jpg]

All runs normally except for when I try to boot from the CD to install the new Windows.

In the old one, I can see the SSD drive and all is normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: 0xc00000e9 = STATUS_UNEXPECTED_IO_ERROR. maybe the Win8.1 ISO/DVD is damaged. get a new copy

Comment: The disc is fine, just tried it within the old OS.